# ASP.NET MVC 5 API, Changing a class in GET function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, debugging, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a dotnet mvc5 application. Here's a function from my api of customer controller

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers()
    {        
        var customerDtos = _context.Customers.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>);

        return Ok(customerDtos);
    }
```

I need to add "TYPEAHEAD" plugin to my application. The video series/instructor I'm following says to make the function code change to

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers(string query = null)
    {
        var customersQuery = _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.MembershipType);

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            customersQuery = customersQuery.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(query));

        var customerDtos = customersQuery
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>);

        return Ok(customerDtos);
```

}

in order to make "TypeAhead" plug in work on my view.

The only **problem is previously while creating customers I didn't feel the need to add "MembershipType" class to my customer. So how do I use the new code without MembershipType.** Is there any other attribute I can replace it with? Name, ID etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.Include(c => c.MembershipType);
```

essentially means that you also want to include the 'child' collection of `MembershipType`
See here for more information on [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx)

For your case, you can simply omit this.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers(string query = null)
{
    var customersQuery = _context.Customers;

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        customersQuery = customersQuery.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(query));

    var customerDtos = customersQuery
        .ToList()
        .Select(Mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerDto>);

    return Ok(customerDtos);    
}
```

You don't need to replace it with anything.

`customersQuery` is then an `IQueryable<Customer>` which the rest of this code can append `Where` clause to.

It is not executed against the database until the `ToList` call.

Comment: Thank You so much for the clarification and linking the documentation. I just added GetCustomers(string query = null) to the previous/old code and it works now, partially.